Redirect to other page (URL) with setting a Redirect option in Callbacks property in Authjs (NextAuth)
I need a condition, where if there is a new user signed up more than 5, the condition will check how many documents from the user collection by more than 5, then the user will be directed to an error page.
I have tried the NextAuth configuration with:

add a Redirect option in Callbacks property, and create a code:

async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
            // EstimatedDocumentCount(): from Mongoose Model query to count documents from a model
            const numUsers = await User.estimatedDocumentCount();

            // It is a condition
            if (numUsers > 5) {
                return `${baseUrl}/peminjaman`;
            }

            // Default redirection (you can customize this as needed)
            return baseUrl;
        }


error appears in CMD:
[auth][error] MongooseError: Operation `users.estimatedDocumentCount()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

error appears on the Web:
on picture I shared




Ensure your MongoDB is properly connected and not timing out. Use:
await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 20000,
});

Use countDocuments() instead for better performance:
const numUsers = await User.countDocuments({});

Ensure async handling in the NextAuth redirect:
async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
  try {
    const numUsers = await User.countDocuments({});
    if (numUsers > 5) return `${baseUrl}/error-page`;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  return baseUrl;
}

Check session logic:
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

export default async function Page() {
  const session = await getSession();
  if (!session) return <div>Not authenticated</div>;
  return <div>Welcome!</div>;
}


But based on MongoDb reference:       https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/count/#:~:text=estimatedDocumentCount()%20is%20faster%20than,and%20supports%20specifying%20a%20filter. estimatedDocumentCount() is faster than countDocuments() because the estimation uses the collection's metadata rather than scanning the collection.
